# Rails Controller Method performs functions before link is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have a small problem.
I have created a activation link mailer that sends a users a activation link in their email before using the platform. 
The mailer does send the activation link and it activates a user once clicked.

The problem I'm having is in the area when a users wants the app to resend the activation link. The issue I'm facing happens when presenting the "Resend" link in the view. Currently anytime this link is presented, the App will automatically preform the method on page load and resend the activation email link before the Resend link is clicked. I only want this to happen when the link is clicked. Haven't been able to figure out where I went wrong.

HERE is my code.

**Sesssions Controller.**

```
  class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]) && user.activated?
            log_in user
            params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
            redirect_to dashboard_index_url
      elsif user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
            message  = "Account not activated."
          message += "Check your email for the activation link. "
          message += "#{view_context.link_to('Resend Link', :method => resend_activation(user))}".html_safe
        flash[:info] = message
            redirect_to root_url
      else
        flash[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        redirect_to '/login'
      end

  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def resend_activation(user)
    p "#"*36, "re-sending activation email", "#"*36
    user.send(:create_activation_digest)
    user.send_activation_email
    user.save
    flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
  end

end
```

**Messages and errors displayed in view**

```
<body>
   <%= render "/layouts/header.html.erb" %>
        <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>

            <div id="yee" class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>">
                <%= message.html_safe %>
              </div>

            <% end %>
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  </body>
```

**Routes**

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'dashboard/index'

  resources :sessions
  resources :users
  resources :static_pages
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
end
```

Comment: can you post your `routes.rb` file here too?

Comment: updated with routes

Comment: can you post your role view file too? The alert view don't show where the link is rendered

Comment: updated with more html in the view

Comment: can you post the `new.html.erb` file? What do you `yeild` on this file?

Comment: Yield loads all your other views into that view. In the end I decided to automatically resend the activation link if a User tries to log in without having activated. It's now a feature

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
message += "#{view_context.link_to('Resend Link', :method => resend_activation(user))}".html_safe
```

To something like:

```
message += "#{view_context.link_to('Resend Link', action: resend_activation, id: user.id))}".html_safe
```

Problem is while building your link html, your `resend_activation` action is being called.